# RequestFactory: error.getExceptionType() returns null in Receiver#onFailure

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

In the server side i have:

```
public void throwException() throws Exception {
        throw new NullPointerException("fslkdjflks");
}
```

in the client side i have:

```
_requestFactory.myService().throwException().fire(new Receiver<Void>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Window.alert(error.getExceptionType() + " " + error.getMessage());

            }

        });
```

error.getExceptionType() returns null and not the type of the exception. Any idea why?

Thanks,
Gilad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default [`ExceptionHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/ExceptionHandler.html) ([`DefaultExeptionHandler`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/DefaultExceptionHandler.java)) does not populate the `exceptionType` and `stackTraceString`. If you want them, you have to provide your own `ExceptionHandler` by [extending `RequestFactoryServlet`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/RequestFactoryServlet.html#RequestFactoryServlet%28com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ExceptionHandler,%20com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator...%29).

Answer (score 5):

Addition to Thomas post, a link how to implement it.

Implement this and you get your StackTrace and find the Problem:
http://cleancodematters.com/2011/05/29/improved-exceptionhandling-with-gwts-requestfactory/

Takes five minutues and saves you much time now and in future.